# How do I write to the log streaming service

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

Sorry for such a stupid simple question but how do I get info to appear in the log streaming service below the code on the develop tab.

It seems pretty straight forward to setup with verbose when you look at the info page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-streaming-logs-and-console

But then none of these do anything...

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("My trace statement");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning("My warning statement");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("My error statement");
```

Comment: what 'severity level' have you chosen for the logging?

Comment: Under Diagnostic Logs > Application Logging Level (Filesystem & Blog) they are both set to on and Verbose. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: You can make custom logger to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put this under `<system.web>` in your `web.config` file:

```
<trace enabled="true" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" localOnly="false" mostRecent="true" pageOutput="false" />
```